Magento 2 PayPal Express Checkout does not appear on Website B, but does on Website A
A Magento 2.4.3-p3 Instance with Website A and Website B set up.
Magento 2 PayPal Express Checkout appears and functions successfully on the default Store View of Website A but not on the Store View of Website B. The core_configuration of Website B is identical to that of Website A. I am using API Signature as the API Authentication Method. When I attach the Store View from Website B to Website A, PayPal Express Checkout appears and works successfully on the Store View from Website B that is now connected to Website A. Why does it not work on Website B?
The API configuration is on default scope. The Magento 2 Cach was flushed.
I expect that PayPal Express Checkout is working fine on Website B, since the configuration is identical to Website A

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
